# SQL rank with priority

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Still learning SQL and would greatly appreciate any help or advice on this one. I have a table with a value column and two ID columns that specify which group that row belongs to, i.e:

> value | GroupA | GroupB
>   12 | 1 | 0
>   16 | 1 | 0
>   19 | 0 | 1
>   11 | 1 | 0
>   30 | 0 | 1
>   16 | 0 | 1

I would like to order this table in a descending order, but give ranking priority to those rows with 1 in group A before ranking those in group B. The output should look something like this.

> value | GroupA | GroupB | Rank
>   12 | 1 | 0 | 2
>   16 | 1 | 0 | 1
>   19 | 0 | 1 | 5
>   11 | 1 | 0 | 3
>   30 | 0 | 1 | 4
>   16 | 0 | 1 | 6

Comment: Why does your table has two bit columns GroupA, GroupB to indicate to which group it belongs? That should be an `int` column as foreign key to the `Group` table and `GroupA`,`GroupB` should be the names of each group.

Comment: Are the two groups mutually exclusive? Your sample data might lead one to believe that a single bit could indicate which group a value belongs to: 1 = A, 0 = B. Could there be additional groups in the future? How would they be ordered when a value belongs to several groups?

Comment: The groups are mutually exclusive. There could however be more groups in the future. I'm not sure I follow as to why I shouldn't store group in bit columns. Are you suggesting one column identifying which group it belongs to?

Comment: If a `value` can belong to only one group then using a single column, as Tim Schmelter suggested, precludes ever accidentally having more than one group selected. It allows easy addition of new groups and can be indexed. Disallow `NULL`s if each `value` _must_ be assigned to a group. (Tip: To respond to a particular user, start your comment with @ and their name, e.g. `@HABO`. They'll be notified of your comment.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm fully agree with TimSchmelter - you shouldn't store group in bit columns. In your current schema query could look like

```
select
    Value, GroupA, GroupB,
    row_number() over(order by GroupA desc, value desc) as [Rank]
from Table1
```

but if you will have more groups in the future, you have to write case inside the over clause

[**sql fiddle example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4df3e/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select *,Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY groupA*100+value desc ) as Rank
from Ranks
order by groupA desc,value desc
```